# How to print receipt using HP Engage One Prime Receipt Printer

Tags: angular, pos, receipt

I'm developing a web application to print receipts using angular. I use HP Engage One Prime POS as client side using the default browser which is Chromium version 74 and HP Engage One Prime Receipt Printer thermal printer. Any suggestions?